# Guacamole PHP front end

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, guacamole

I've recently installed Guacamole on a dev Ubuntu server and I'm looking to build a PHP front end 'dashboard' type system the only thing that is giving me trouble is authenticating via PHP to the same MySQL DB as it uses a password hash (sha256) and a password salt.

Every time I try to login i get Username or Password invalid, however, I know it is correct because I set it within Guacamole.

**Below is the MySQL table structure:**

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username            | varchar(128) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password_hash       | binary(32)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password_salt       | binary(32)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| disabled            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| expired             | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| access_window_start | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| access_window_end   | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| valid_from          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| valid_until         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timezone            | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**This is my login.php**

```
    <?php 
        require("config.php"); 
        $submitted_username = ''; 
        if(!empty($_POST)){ 
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    user_id, 
                    username, 
                    password_hash, 
                    password_salt
                FROM guacamole_user
                WHERE 
                    username = :username 
            "; 
            $query_params = array( 
                ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
            ); 

            try{ 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
            $login_ok = false; 
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row){ 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['password_salt']); 
                for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
                    $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['password_salt']);
                } 
                if($check_password === $row['password_hash']){
                    $login_ok = true;
                } 
            } 

            if($login_ok){ 
                unset($row['password_salt']); 
                unset($row['password_hash']); 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row;  
                header("Location: secret.php"); 
                die("Redirecting to: secret.php"); 
            } 
            else{ 
                print("Login Failed."); 
                $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
            } 
        } 
    ?> 

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background: url(assets/bglight.png); }
            .hero-unit { background-color: #fff; }
            .center { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand">PHP Signup + Bootstrap Example</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
              <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Log In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                    <form action="index.php" method="post"> 
                        Username:<br /> 
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
                        <br /><br /> 
                        Password:<br /> 
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
                        <br /><br /> 
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /> 
                    </form> 
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container hero-unit">
        <h1>There's secret content to be had within!</h1>
        <p>But you can't access it just yet! You'll need to log in first. Use Bootstrap's nifty navbar dropdown to access the form.</p>
        <h2>There are 2 ways you can log in:</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Try out your own user + password with the <strong>Register</strong> button in the navbar.</li>
            <li>Use the default credentials to save time:<br />
                <strong>user:</strong> admin<br />
                <strong>pass:</strong> password<br /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```